# Relation "pk" already exists in Postgresql 9.1

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1, psql

I am new to Postgres/PostGIS, currently following a PostGIS book. When I tried one of their example's query, I get the error below stating that the `relation "pk" already exists`. Does this mean that 2 tables cannot have constraints with the same names?

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE roads(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, road_name character varying(100));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'roads', 'geom', 4269, 'LINESTRING',2);

CREATE TABLE roads_NE(CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (gid))
INHERITS (roads);

ALTER TABLE roads_NE
ADD CONSTRAINT chk CHECK (state
IN ('MA', 'ME', 'NH', 'VT', 'CT', 'RI'));

CREATE TABLE roads_SW(CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (gid))
INHERITS (roads);

ALTER TABLE roads_SW
ADD CONSTRAINT chk CHECK (state IN ('AZ', 'NM', 'NV'));
```

**Error:**

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pk" for table "roads_sw"


ERROR:  relation "pk" already exists

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "pk" already exists
SQL state: 42P07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use a different name within a database

Comment: s/within a database/within a *schema*